# R regex match '\' and newline in dataframe to create columns with new values

Tags: r

I am trying to split values in a dataframe column that looks like this:

```
Apple\Banana
Drink
---
Drink\Cup Cake
Apple
--
Fudge\Grape\Ham
Cup Cake
---
```

I am trying to match both newline and '\' using regex in strsplit.

currently I am using this:

```
strsplit(as.character(df$Food), "[\\\\ \n]")
```

However, it is also matching the *space* and splitting up "CupCake" to "Cup" and "Cake"

I am trying to figure out the proper regex for this matching.

My aim is to split the multiple values to multiple food columns in the dataframe called Food.1, Food.2, Food.3, etc. Is there standard way to do the split and create new columns in a dataframe? I think strsplit may not be the best way forward.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a space in the pattern. Try putting the newline first then you don't need a space:

```
strsplit(as.character(df$Food), "[\n\\\\]")
```